# Is it Possible to write javascript function code in java mail body?

Tags: java

I am trying to put JavaScript code in javaMail class method.

Im am getting the template and i click on button the click function was not

calling what mistake i have done any body can please help.

I am Placing my code below:

```
 String body="<!DOCTYPE html>"
    + "<html>"
    + "<head>"
    + "<script>"
    + "function myFunction(){document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML ='Paragraph changed.';}"
    + "</script>"
    + "</head>"
    + "<body>"
    + "<h1>JavaScript in Head</h1>"
    + "<p id='demo'>A Paragraph.</p>"
    + "<button type='button' onclick='myFunction()'>Try it</button>"
    + "</body>"
    + "</html>";
```

Adavance Thanks,

Comment: Any errors in console ?

Comment: no errors.But click function is not changing.

Comment: @MadanMohan see source of your email

Answer (score 4):

Sure, it is possible. However it will not work in most email viewers. The reason is security. Javascript injection is the easiest way to get access to user private data. If email viewer runs script embedded into email body the script is running in user's browser and therefore has access to user's cookie, so it can steel the user's session that allows hacker to access the rest of the user's private data.

Comment: Thank you alex for sharing your knowledge with me.